# WPF Mouse Position UI Control Hwnd

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

Other than WPF, we can easily find out Handle Of the Control (Like Command Button, Text Box etc.) using Mouse Point.

But in WPF, there is only one Hwnd of Parent window.

Is there any way in WPF to findout a User Control of another WPF executable when Mouse is placed over that User Control?

For Example:

I have a WPF Application A with TextBox
I have another WPF Application B with Different UI Controls
In Application A, I have a timer control which tracks Mouse Point. And When Mouse is over any of the Control in Application B, I want to display It's Hwnd or Control Name in to the Text Box of Application A.

Comment: google UI Automation WPF.

Comment: Thanks HighCore for the information